# When data changes in my chatbot, page should get reloaded with new data

Tags: javascript, python, flask

In web page (chatbot) in flask python, when data changes (new messages enter the new data), page should get reloaded with new data .Pip installs are done

**Here I am using a Pretrained model of chatbot(DialoGPT-small) which will answers from the bot side.**

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request, jsonify
from datetime import datetime
from transformers import AutoModelForCausalLM, AutoTokenizer
import torch
import time


app = Flask(__name__)
global chat_data
global tokenizer
global model
global chat_history_ids

chat_data=[
        {'typer': 'User', 'message': 'Hello! I am your New friend', 'Time': '12:45'},
    ]
chat_history_ids = None

tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained("microsoft/DialoGPT-small")
model = AutoModelForCausalLM.from_pretrained("microsoft/DialoGPT-small")
print('Model loaded')

@app.route("/",methods=['POST', 'GET'])
def chatpage():
    global chat_data
    global tokenizer
    global model
    global chat_history_ids

  

    if 'messages' in request.form:

        new_user_input_ids = tokenizer.encode(request.form['messages'] + tokenizer.eos_token, return_tensors='pt')

        bot_input_ids = torch.cat([chat_history_ids, new_user_input_ids], dim=-1) if chat_history_ids!=None else new_user_input_ids

        chat_history_ids = model.generate(bot_input_ids, max_length=1000, pad_token_id=tokenizer.eos_token_id)


        bot_data = (tokenizer.decode(chat_history_ids[:, bot_input_ids.shape[-1]:][0], skip_special_tokens=True))

        chat_data = chat_data + [{'typer': 'Man', 'message': request.form['messages'], 'Time': datetime.now().strftime("%H:%M")}]
        chat_data = chat_data + [{'typer': 'User', 'message': bot_data, 'Time': datetime.now().strftime("%H:%M")}]
        

    return render_template('Chat.htm',chat_data=chat_data)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True, use_reloader=True)
```

**My HTML CODE

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js" integrity="sha512-894YE6QWD5I59HgZOGReFYm4dnWc1Qt5NtvYSaNcOP+u1T9qYdvdihz0PPSiiqn/+/3e7Jo4EaG7TubfWGUrMQ==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://pro.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.10.0/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-AYmEC3Yw5cVb3ZcuHtOA93w35dYTsvhLPVnYs9eStHfGJvOvKxVfELGroGkvsg+p" crossorigin="anonymous"/>
<title>ChatBot</title>


<script>
    $(function(){
        console.log("Went in first time")
    $('#message_send').click(function(){
        $.ajax({
            data : {
                'messages' : document.getElementById('message_input').value
            },
            type: 'POST',
            url : "{{url_for('chatpage')}}",
            success: function(response) {
                console.log("Downloaded")
                location.reload(true);
            },
            error: function(error) {
                console.log(error)
            },
        });
    });

});
</script>



<head>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="window">
        


        <div id="message_view" class="invisible-scrollbar ">
            {% for chatted_data in chat_data%}

                {% if chatted_data.typer == "Man" %}
                <div class="right_box_container reloadPage();">
                    <div class="message_box right_message_box">
                        {{chatted_data.message}}
                        <div class="timestamp">{{chatted_data.Time}}</div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                
                {% else %}
                <div class="gap">

                </div>


                <div class="left_box_container reloadPage();">
                    <div class="message_box left_message_box">
                        {{chatted_data.message}}
                        <div class="timestamp">12:38 PM</div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                {% endif %}

                

            {% endfor %}    
            


        </div>

        
        <form style="box-shadow: 0 5px 50px #b5b5b5;" >
            <div id="message_container">
                <textarea type="text" class="form-control invisible-scrollbar" placeholder="Type here..." id="message_input"></textarea>
            </div>
            <div id="message_send" class="ripple">
                <button id="send_button">
                    <i class="fas fa-caret-right" id="send_button"></i>
                </button>   
            </div>
        </form> 
    </div>




</body>
</html>
```

**The problem is that the page is not reloading with the new data, So I want a code to Reload the page, each time when new data gets added to chat_data(Dictionary)**
*{The page should reload after the bots message is added to the Chat_data}*

Comment: Why oh Why use AJAX and then reload. Just submit to the server and return a new page or don't reload but show the new data

Comment: I have used ajax to transfer the input from html to the python code, can you explain your method to reload

Comment: `reloadPage();` is not a valid class name by the way

Answer (score 0):

Change your success to

```
document.getElementById("message_view").innerHTML => `<div class="right_box_container">
                <div class="message_box right_message_box">
                    ${document.getElementById('message_input').value}
                    <div class="timestamp">${new Date().toLocaleDateString()}</div>
                </div>
            </div>`
```

No need to reload

Comment: But the message from the bot/DialoGPT model (which comes from the Flask code) will not come.

Comment: I have no idea what you mean. If you return some JSON you can parse it from the response `success: function(response) {`